# Custom Calendar By 3 UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, calendar

I want to create a calender with use of only 3 `collectionViewCell`.

I have achieved this by 12 `UICollectionViewCell` for 1 year:

[image].

but now I want to make it work by just 3 `collectionViewCell`.

I want to implement below logic. but not getting idea how to do.

For example, current scenario is:

```
indexPath.item 0 - cell for previous mointh(JAN),
indexPath.item 1 - cell for current month(FEB),
indexPath.item 2 - cell for next month(MAR).
```

Now,
when user scrolls to next month(MAR), at that time I want to remove `indexPath.item = 0`(JAN), and shift remaining cells on left. 
after that add next month cell(APR) at `indexPath.item = 2`

so it will be like this after one scroll:

```
indexPath.item 0 - cell for previous mointh(FEB),
indexPath.item 1 - cell for current month(MAR),
indexPath.item 2 - cell for next month(APR).
```

Comment: Please explain more on what you want. You want any new suggestions or have any coding problem? Your question seems to be incomplete.

Comment: I have created custom calendar using UiCollectionView.
right now I have limit with only 1 year calendar is display.
but i want to render 3 month at a time. then remaining are created when I Swipe, and old month also removed.
so at a time only 3 months available in UiCollectionView.